# Ios app crash after install background mode(latest version)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

ionic app crash in ios version 12.2 after install background mode(latest version). i am also updated background Mode from git but app crash initially.
Below Exception when app initialized

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]
>   : this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _alwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority.'

My confilg.xml below

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="https://github.com/tushe/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git" />
```

My package.json below

"cordova-plugin-background-mode": "git+https://github.com/tushe/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git",

I am also try to different solution

1- forKey:@"requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback"];
2-

Comment: Having the exact same issue ... it's disappointing seeing no one answering here.